# How to add a substring to a string as a column

Tags: bash, dash, dmenu

The title may not be the best at describing the issue, but this was the best I could come up with, moving on to describe what I'm trying to do, I use artix runit as my os, and it is tedious to create a symlink for every service I want to enable, so I created this script to make it easier.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

rundir="/run/runit/service"
svdir="/etc/runit/sv"

for SERVICE in $(ls $svdir); do
    [[ -d "$rundir/$SERVICE" ]] && output="$output$SERVICE        linked: yes\n" || output="$output$SERVICE        linked: no\n"
done

service=$(printf "$output" | dmenu -l 10) || exit 1

if printf "$service" | grep -Fqe "linked: yes"; then
    service=$(printf "$service" | awk '{print $1}')
    sudo -A rm "$rundir/$service"
else
    service=$(printf "$service" | awk '{print $1}')
    sudo -A ln -s "$svdir/$service" "$rundir/"
fi
```

Which checks all the services that can be enabled in `/etc/runit/sv` and checks if they are already enabled by seeing if they exist in `/run/runit/service` if it does it will add `linked: yes` at the end of the dmenu list and if it doesn't, it adds `linked: no` the problem is that the service's names vary so adding those things will result in this inconsistency:
[image: inconsistency]

as you can see as service's names vary the location of the text at the end change which is not very appealing to the eye I would say, so I would like to ask if there's a solution to this, if there's none I guess I would add the `linked: xxx` at the beginning since that would solve the problem, but it's my last resort.
And if anyone wants to point out a more efficient way to write the code please do, this is my first bash script and I have much to learn.
Note: I use dash as sh so i can't use any kind of bashisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `printf` to format the argument to a specific length. I chose a left alignment of 20 characters, adjust it as needed.

[image: dmenu screenshot]

Some adjustments to your code:

```
#!/bin/sh

rundir="/run/runit/service"
svdir="/etc/runit/sv"

cd "$svdir"
result=$(
    for service in *; do
        printf '%-20s linked: %s\n' "$service" $([ -d "$rundir/$service" ] && echo yes || echo no)
    done | dmenu -l 10
) || exit 1

service=$(echo "$result" | awk '{print $1}')
case $result in
    *yes)
        sudo -A rm "$rundir/$service"
        ;;
    *no)
        sudo -A ln -s "$svdir/$service" "$rundir/"
esac
```

List of changes:

- `[ expression ]` for the test, `[[ ... ]]` doesn't exist in dash
- `*` instead of `ls`, but I needed a `cd` for this to work
- removed `$output` variable, pipe the output of the loop to `dmenu`
- case statement instead of if-else